# Suppress 'file truncated' messages when using tail

Tags: grep, tail, output

I'm tailing a log file using `tail -f messages.log` and this is part of the output:

> ```
> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
> Fusce eget tellus sit amet odio porttitor rhoncus. 
> Donec consequat diam sit amet tellus viverra pellentesque. 
> tail: messages.log: file truncated
> Suspendisse at risus id neque pharetra finibus in facilisis ipsum.
> ```

It shows `tail: messages.log: file truncated` when the file gets truncated automatically and that's supposed to happen, but I just want `tail` to show me the output without this truncate message.

I've tried using `tail -f messages.log | grep -v truncated` but it shows me the message anyway.

Is there any method to suppress this message?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That message is output on *stderr* like all warning and error messages.

You can either drop all the error output:

```
tail -f file 2> /dev/null
```

Or to filter out only the error messages that contain `truncate`:

```
{ tail -f file 2>&1 >&3 3>&- | grep -v truncated >&2 3>&-;} 3>&1
```

That means however that you lose the exit status of `tail`. A few shells have a `pipefail` option (enabled with `set -o pipefail`) for that pipeline to report the exit status of `tail` if it fails. `zsh` and `bash` can also report the status of individual components of the pipeline in their `$pipestatus`/`$PIPESTATUS` array.

With `zsh` or `bash`, you can use:

```
tail -f file 2> >(grep -v truncated >&2)
```

But beware that the `grep` command is not waited for, so the error messages if any may end up being displayed after `tail` exits and the shell has already started running the next command in the script.

In `zsh`, you can address that by writing it:

```
{ tail -f file; } 2> >(grep -v truncated >&2)
```

That is discussed in the `zsh` documentation at `info zsh 'Process Substitution'`:

> There is an additional problem with `>(PROCESS)`; when this is attached to
>   an external command, the parent shell does not wait for PROCESS to
>   finish and hence an immediately following command cannot rely on the
>   results being complete.  The problem and solution are the same as
>   described in the section *MULTIOS* in *note Redirection::*.  Hence in a
>   simplified version of the example above:
>
> ```
> paste <(cut -f1 FILE1) <(cut -f3 FILE2) > >(PROCESS)
> ```
>
> (note that no MULTIOS are involved), PROCESS will be run asynchronously
>   as far as the parent shell is concerned.  The workaround is:
>
> ```
> { paste <(cut -f1 FILE1) <(cut -f3 FILE2) } > >(PROCESS)
> ```
>
> The extra processes here are spawned from the parent shell which will
>   wait for their completion.

Comment: Is there a reason you're preferring a subshell `(` `)` over a complex command `{` `}`?

Comment: @TomHale. No good reason. See edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

It happened because file content

**is overwritten with overwrite `>` - not adding with append `>>`**.

Comment: good answer... this was the root cause in my scenario

Answer (score 2):

If `grep` doesn't get rid of the output, it's most likely being printed on standard error. The simplest way to get rid of that is to simply dump it:

```
tail -f messages.log 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Does the trick, but also suppresses other messages.

Comment: Yep, @StéphaneChazelas's got a solution which is more complex but only ignores the relevant message.