# Tail -f breaks when file truncated

Tags: osx, tail

I am using `tail -f` (in Terminal on Mac OS X el capitan) to view the live changes to my file (the results of pulling data from a database using a PERL script). However, sometimes, the Perl script will truncate the file and add new data to it. Sometimes, when this happens, it gives me this message:

```
tail: test.txt: file truncated
```

And then does not show any contents of the file afterwards. This seems to only happen when I'm replacing a file with LESS rows than before. When the new rows are longer than before running the script, I do not get this error and the `tail -f` continues to work. I have confirmed that there are, in fact, data in the file that `tail -f` is not showing after getting this (error?) message.

I've seen this similar question: [Suppress 'file truncated' messages when using tail](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169054/suppress-file-truncated-messages-when-using-tail)

```
tail -f test.txt 2> /dev/null
```

But that just suppresses the message and still breaks, it doesn't continue to show me the shorter, truncated file contents.

Is there a better command to use to live view changes to the file? Or a flag for `tail -f` to not care when the file is truncated?

Comment: Have you tried tail -F which is the same as -f but also implies --retry option

Comment: Just tried, but it didn't work.  Same thing as above even with `-F` -- it doesn't display contents of new file (when it is shorter results). Just stops at the File Truncate message and doesn't return to terminal until I command+C. I find it very weird that it always works when the results are longer than the previous results. It's always truncating the file, regardless.

Comment: As stated in comments below by @roaima, Macs don't have --retry...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have pointed out, the `tail` command that ships with OS X does not have the `--retry` option. However, you could simply install the GNU version of tail which has that option; it is part of the [GNU coreutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tail-invocation.html). For example, if you use MacPorts you could install them by running `sudo port install coreutils`.

An alternative to live watching a file is the `watch` command, which unfortunately also doesn't ship with OS X. However, you can use [this simple workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9574123/7932936).

Comment: Workaround is great! Good find. Eventually led me to this script: http://daniel.lubarov.com/simple-watch-script-for-osx

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tail-F` script. It takes a single argument - the file to tail. There are probably better options (such as installing GNU `tail`), but it's here to demonstrate that simple versions of tools can often be built from the parts available.

```
#!/bin/bash
#
file="$1"
size=$(stat -c '%s' "$file" 2>/dev/null)
test -z "$size" && echo "No file '$file'" >&2

while sleep 1
do
    n_size=$(stat -c '%s' "$file" 2>/dev/null)

    if [[ -n "$n_size" ]]
    then
        if [[ 0 == "$size" ]]
        then
            # Output whole file (so far)
            dd bs=1K if="$file" 2>/dev/null
            size="$n_size"

        elif [[ "$n_size" > "${size:-0}" ]]
        then
            # Output new part of file
            dd bs="$size" skip=1 if="$file" 2>/dev/null
            size="$n_size"

        elif [[ -z "$size" ]]
        then
            echo "New file '$file'" >&2
            size=0

        elif [[ "$n_size" < "${size:-0}" ]]
        then
            echo "Rewinding file '$file'" >&2
            size=0
        fi
    fi
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `tail --f=name`

The default value of the `-f` flag is `descriptor`.
Changing it to name, `tail` will follow the file name and will continue to display even after the file is truncated.

PS. You will still receive the message `tail: File truncated`

Comment: As pointed out in all three of the other visible answers, this is **not the GNU command**.  The question does very clearly state MacOS.

Answer (score -2):

The following command keep retry the file even it is removed or inaccessible. It will again prints the contents after creating it.

```
tail -F filename --retry
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work.  Same thing as above even with -F and --retry -- it doesn't display contents of new file (when it is shorter results). Just stops at the File Truncate message and doesn't return to terminal until I command+C. I find it very weird that it always works when the results are longer than the previous results. It's always truncating the file, regardless.

Comment: Mac systems don't have `--retry`

Comment: Is this just not possible then with Mac systems?